# How to make the docker container search the file within the host rather than within the container?

Tags: python, docker, containers

I have a **python script** which takes the input file path from the user processes that file and gives the output file in the location specified by the user in the terminal. Below is my code which takes the files path.

```
inputfilepath = input("Enter the input file path")
print(inputfilepath)
outputfilepath = input("Enter the output file path")
print(outputfilepath)
inputPath = inputfilepath
```

This python code works fine if I run it in the Pycharm but if I create a docker image of the same code and enter the input file path, it gives "File not found error".

[Providing the input and output file path to the running container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSkhQ.png)

and

[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psp89.png)

Because if I give the file path of the host/local machine, **it searches for that path within the container's working director not within the local machine**.

How do I make the container search the file path on the local file system?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should mount your files (or the directory containing the files) from the host to the container.

Assuming you want the same path in the container as in the host:

```
docker run \
  --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/directory,target=/path/to/directory
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) about bind mounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day. I used your command along with -it and image name at the end and it worked. 
                                                                                   
**docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/home/poorna/inputfiles,target=/app/files imagename.**